# Android Grid View, Making a Word Search Game in android

Tags: android, wordsearch

I want to develop a Word Search game in android and the problem is how to create a layout

e.g http://apps.talkandroid.com/games/brain/631-com+dahl+brendan+wordsearch+view/

like this one and how to detect individual character in it. and read word from files and display in the view. need help

Answer (score 1):

What exaclty is your problem? GridView would work fantastically and allows you to detects click real nice and easy and allows for easy content rewrites. Do you need help with how to do a gridview?

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Comment: I basically want the grid to fill from words that are read from some raw file e.g *.txt. and then in Grid every individual character is click-able, that words can be selected by user vertically,horizontal and diagonal. e.g this game want to build the same thing in android 

http://www.brainjar.com/java/games/wordsearch/

Comment: Right, you already said all of that. What `exactly` is your issue? that seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA  I know it's a pretty old post but I'm working on a similar problem anyway. As per your suggestion if I use grid view can the textviews be set dynamically? Like if the word is WORD then W & O in a row and R & D in the next row. But if the word is BENDING then B,E,N,D in the 1st row and I,N,G the 2nd row. Please suggest if possible.

Comment: Ya, you could do something like have all of your characters in an array, then mode (%) the character array by the row length.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA ok. Any suggestion on how can I create the texviews dynically for this purpose? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. The GridView's adapter will create your TextViews. You don't need to worry about creating them dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I might be late to the party, an easy solution to this problem: (A word puzzle Dictionary in 30 minutes crash course)

1. Download a dictionary
2. Convert the dictionary into an SQLite Db table
3. Prepare layout (Grid View, on touch listeners, cursor adapters)
4. Use a filter query provider on your GridView
5. Enjoy!